# Why the result is 1

Tags: c

```
void main()
{
    int x=5,y=10,z=10;
    if(x=6)
    {
    x=y==z;
    }
    printf("%d",x);
}
```

I don't understand why entering the if statement since the value of x is 5.

Comment: `x=6` -> `x==6`

Comment: eh.... why was a request for an explanation closed as not reproducible/typo? That makes no sense potato. Be careful!!

Comment: `int x=5,...;  if(x=6) { ...` same as `int x=5,...;  x=6; if(x) { ...` same as `int x;  x=6; if(x != 0) { ...`

Comment: Thank you :D ,i understand now

Answer (score 2):

`x=6` isn't a comparison; it's an assignment that evaluates to `6`, which is true. You should have used `x==6`.

Enable your compiler's warnings! It should have warned you of this. I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with gcc.

Comment: I use online compiler

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's because x is being assigned as a value of `(y==z)` which is 1 (since it evaluates to `True`). `==` has higher precedence than `=`.

Comment: i understand True value ,but at the beginning x has a value of 5, why it enters the loop for I don't understand, nowhere do I see that it is incremented by one to reach 6

Comment: @Stefania, There's no loop in your code.

Comment: @ikegami if(x=6)
    {
    x=y==z;
    }

Comment: @Stefania, There's no loop in your comment. That's an "if statement". A loop is a statement that causes code to be executed multiple times. Loop = going in circles.

Comment: @ikegami shouldn't the if be executed only if x had problem 6 from the beginning?

Comment: @Stefania, No, why would it? An assignment evaluates to the assigned value.

Comment: @ikegami i use google translate,I understand it, but to write I make mistakes, so I write in my language and it translates automatically

Comment: @ikegami I don't understand, so is it correct for the result to be 1?
I from my logic knew that one enters if only if the condition is fulfilled and from my point of view it is not fulfilled

Comment: It is fulfilled. `6` is not zero, so it's true

Comment: @Stefania If you've read ikegami's comments, you'll find out that "an assignment evaluates to the assigned value." In this case, as ikegami explained, `x=6` returns 6 which evaluates to `True`. Thus, it would enter the if statement and `x` will be assigned to 1 since `y==z` is `True`.

Comment: @Stefania It may not be obvious from all these comments what the real issue is.  You wrote `if(x=6)`.  But that was a mistake (and it's a very easy one to make).  You meant to type `if(x==6)`.  You wanted to say, "do this thing if `x` is equal to 6".  But by typing `if(x=6)`, what you got was "Assign 6 to `x`, and then do this thing if what I just assigned was not 0".

Comment: @SteveSummit aaa ,now i understant if (x=6) is different from if (x==6)  Thank you Steve and thank you all.